# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js"

Tags: chart.js

Estoy importando el módulo **ChartDataLabels** de ChartJS, pero no es muestran los gráficos porque según el error de consola no se encuentra el módulo **chart.js**. Recibo el siguiente mensaje de error: ***Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".***
El problema surge en las dos primeras líneas de mi archivo .js en la que importo las librerías necesarias para utilizar el módulo correspondiente.

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const fechas = ['2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-09-01'];

const TPRIFacebook = ['2023-06-01 00:15:54', '2023-06-01 00:23:56', '2023-06-01 00:11:14', '2023-06-01 00:11:14'];
const TPRFacebook = ['2023-06-01 00:13:25', '2023-06-01 00:19:02', '2023-06-01 00:10:07', '2023-06-01 00:10:07'];

// Función para formatear las etiquetas de los tooltips
function formatTooltip(value) {
  const date = new Date(value);
  return 'TPRI ' + date.toLocaleTimeString('es-AR', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' });
}

const config = {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: fechas,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'TPRI Facebook',
      data: TPRIFacebook
    }, {
      label: 'TPR Facebook',
      data: TPRFacebook
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: { unit: 'month' }
      },
      y: {
        type: 'time',
        time: { unit: 'second', displayFormats: { second: 'HH:mm:ss' } },
        min: '2023-06-01 00:00:00',
        max: '2023-06-01 01:00:00',
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 3600
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (context) => formatTooltip(context.parsed.y)
        }
      },
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (dato) => dato,
      }
    }
  }
};

const fbChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('chartFB'),
  config
);
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Métricas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="cols-2">
      <div class="barra">
        <canvas id="chartWA"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="barra">
        <canvas id="chartFB"></canvas>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="cols-2">
      
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <!-- En esta línea llamo al módulo -->
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./src/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Desde ya agradezco al que pueda ayudarme ¡Saludos!